# Extract the elements from a super list using the textual information available in sub list

Tags: python

My code did not work when I wanted to extract the elements from a super_list using the textual information available in my_list:

```
import glob    
super_list = glob.glob('*.jpg')

print (super_list)

E:\\a2001.jpg
E:\\a2008.jpg
E:\\a2007.jpg
E:\\a2002.jpg
E:\\a2009.jpg
E:\\a2009.jpg

my_list = ['2001','2002','2009']
```

HERE IS THE PROBLEM IN CODING

```
result_list = [x for x in super_list if (y for y in my_list) in x]
print (result_list)
```

The result_list should be:

```
E:\\a2001.jpg
E:\\a2002.jpg
E:\\a2009.jpg
E:\\a2009.jpg
```

Waiting for the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list comprehension syntax is slightly off.  It should be like this:

```
result_list = [x for x in super_list if any(y in x for y in my_list)]
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> super_list = [
...     'E:\\a2001.jpg',
...     'E:\\a2008.jpg',
...     'E:\\a2007.jpg',
...     'E:\\a2002.jpg',
...     'E:\\a2009.jpg',
...     'E:\\a2009.jpg'
... ]
>>> my_list = ['2001','2002','2009']
>>> result_list = [x for x in super_list if any(y in x for y in my_list)]
>>> result_list
['E:\\a2001.jpg', 'E:\\a2002.jpg', 'E:\\a2009.jpg', 'E:\\a2009.jpg']
>>>
```

Here is a reference on [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and one on [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, waiting for 15 reputation for up-voting you. @iCodez

Answer (score 1):

```
result_list = [x for x in super_list 
               if any(y in x for y in my_list) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, waiting for 15 reputation for up-voting you. @unutbu